# Typescript module is not defined

Tags: typescript

I'm working on upgrading to Angular2 RC1 and I've suddenly got the following errors on a pretty simple typescript server :
[image]

I have installed the typings I though were required and I'm building it using gulp:
typings.json:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
  "es6-collections": "registry:dt/es6-collections#0.5.1+20160316155526",
  "es6-promise": "registry:dt/es6-promise#0.0.0+20160423074304",
  "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
  "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20160317120654",
  "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#0.0.0+20160322035842",
  "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160505172921",
  "require": "registry:dt/require#2.1.20+20160316155526",
  "serve-static": "registry:dt/serve-static#0.0.0+20160501131543"
  }
}
```

gulp task for proxy building:

```
gulp.task('build:proxy', function () {
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
    var tsResult = gulp.src(['proxy/**/*.ts','!proxy/typings/**/*.*'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(concat('proxy.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

and tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "proxy/typings/main",
    "proxy/typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "disableCompileOnSave": true,
  "compileOnSave" : false
}
```

Since everything seems to look like before I've kept my imports the same, for example `import express = require('express')`. I can't seem to figure out what I have to do to get those modules in.

Comment: Have you checked `typings/main.d.ts`?

Comment: does your source ts files reside inside proxy\<another folder>\ts files?

Comment: @Zen Yes, it looks good!

Comment: @MadhuRanjan Only have one ts file called proxy.ts inside the proxy folder. I've also tried moving everything to the root folder but same problems.

Answer (score 1):

Put a new main.d.ts inside proxy folder with below content

```
 /// <reference path="./typings/main.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Tried it, with that I'm getting duplicate identifier ( also tried excluding the main.d.ts in typings from tsconfig and still getting the duplicate error).

Answer (score 1):

I answered on the GitHub issue (https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/491). In summary, you need to correct the `gulp.src()` call to not ignore *all* typings and only ignore either *main* or *browser* typings. E.g. `gulp.src(['proxy/**/*.ts', '!proxy/typings/main/**', '!proxy/typings/main.d.ts']`.

Comment: I have  question about an `npm` package that you published.  Are you willing to help resolve it?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162115/what-is-the-user-in-this-node-js-package-code