# What is the user in this node.js package code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, npm, oauth-2.0

I am studying [the `client-oauth2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-oauth2) `npm` package.  The code sample from the link in the preceding sentence includes the word `user`.  **What does `user` refer to?  Is `user` a built in type?  Or does the developer need to create their own `user` model class?**  If so, please give a good example of how to create and integrate a `user` model class.  Any links to documentation about `user` or code samples for `user` for this package would also be greatly appreciated.

Here is a code snipped from the link above which includes the word `user`:

```
app.get('/auth/github/callback', function (req, res) {
  githubAuth.code.getToken(req.url)
    .then(function (user) {
      console.log(user) //=> { accessToken: '...', tokenType: 'bearer', ... } 

      // Refresh the current users access token. 
      user.refresh().then(function (updatedUser) {
        console.log(updatedUser === user) //=> true 
      })

      // Sign API requests on behalf of the current user. 
      user.sign({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://example.com'
      })

      // We should store the token into a database. 
      return res.send(user.accessToken)
    })
}
```

The following methods and properties seem to be required of a `user` object:

```
user.refresh()  
user.sign({method: 'get',  
    url: 'http://example.com'})    
user.accessToken
```

It seems obvious that `user.accessToken` stores the user's OAuth2 access token in memory.  **But what specifically do the `refresh()` and `sign(...)` methods do?  And what code should be used to implement them, if they are not built-in types?**

Comment: user is a parameter . user is object having functions and the info of the connected socket

Comment: @Zoe OK.  But how to implement?  And what documentation?

Comment: @DollarCoffee it's passed into the callback from a call to a `githubAuth` method, so I suggest you start looking there. You don't need to implement it, it's being provided, you just need to use it.

Comment: What do you meant by implement ? You already know the package name and are implementing it . Read the Readme for documentation :)
https://github.com/mulesoft/js-client-oauth2

Comment: @Zoe I am asking what code to use so that `user` is defined when the control flow reaches it in the code shown in the OP.  I read the documentation before posting the question.  The docs that I read do not show how to create a `user` class, or how to import a built-in `user` from a library.  I am very new to `Node.js`.  I need to see code.

Comment: @DollarCoffee `user` is the callback argument, it could very well be called `object` or `foo`. It is an object in JavaScript that contains a couple of helper methods, and also some properties. It is the same object returned as the result of calling `createToken`. Here is the relevant code: https://github.com/mulesoft/js-client-oauth2/blob/master/client-oauth2.js#L282-L296